# Parsing JSON File from XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I would like to use data within a JSON file which I get by using the XMLHttpRequest. I already checked that I recieve the file.

```
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = this.responseText;
    }
};
var obj = xhttp.open("GET", "../data/data.json", true);
xhttp.send();
var obj1 = JSON.parse(obj);
a0 = obj1.a0;
```

This is my JSON file.

```
{"a0":2, "a1": -2.356, "a2": 4.712}
```

I can't find the mistake I am doing here. Can you help?

Comment: There is a pretty obvious difference between `innerHTML = this.responseText;` and `obj = xhttp.open("GET", "../data/data.json", true);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = this.responseText;
        var obj=this.responseText;
        var obj1 = JSON.parse(obj);
        a0 = obj1.a0;
    }
};
xhttp.open("GET", "../data/data.json", true);
xhttp.send();
```

You need to get the response text inside the xhttp response.

Answer (score 0):

onreadystatechange is a callback. That means that it's called asynchonously when the request ended. SO a part of your code is misplaced. Here the correction:

```
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = this.responseText;
        var obj1 = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
        var a0 = obj1.a0;
    }
};
xhttp.open("GET", "../data/data.json", true);
xhttp.send();
```